# Realm Query with 2 Columns and distinct

Tags: android, realm

I would like to create a Realm Android query, but dont know how to do this.
My realm Object is the following.

```
public class test extends RealmObject {
     @PrimaryKey 
     int id;
     String test1;
     String test2;
}
```

My query should search in test1 and test2. So if either test1 or test2 is equals to the filter String the RealmObject should be inserted into my list. It is possible that test1 and test2 both have the same value. If this is the case the Object should only appear once in my list and not twice.

```
My query which is not working:
 List<test> games = db.where(test.class)
                .contains("test1", charText, 
                 Case.INSENSITIVE).distinct().where(test.class)
                 contains("test2", charText, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                .distinct();
```

At last I want to sort the list after test1.

Comment: Why did you rollback [jonnyandrew's edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16779333)?  As far as I could tell, it just fixed some spelling and grammar and made the question a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`RealmQuery::or`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#or--) to combine the conditions:

```
List<test> games = db.where(test.class)
                     .contains("test1", charText, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                     .or()
                     .contains("test2", charText, Case.INSENSITIVE)
                     .findAllSorted("test1");
```

You can find other examples of this type of query in the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries)

Even if the test1 and test2 contain the same value, the same record will not appear twice in the list so you do not need to add the distinct constraint on your query.